# Code logic to manage a @RequestParam with different params

Tags: java, spring, controller

I am creating a service to retrieve data

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{productId}/freeTrial", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public RestResponse<List<RetrieveFreeTrialResponse>> retrieveServiceFreeTrialsByProductIdWithParam(
        @PathVariable String productId,
        @RequestParam(value = "addFields", required = false) String field) {
    if("includeDeleted".equals(field)) {
        return retrieveFreeTrialsActivity.retrieveFreeTrialsByProductId(productId, true);
    } else {
        return retrieveFreeTrialsActivity.retrieveFreeTrialsByProductId(productId, false);
    }
}
```

I was working with either no param or with `includeDeleted`. Now I have to add the possibility for `addFields` to also accept another value: `onlyActive`.

Is there any way to avoid writing 4 `if`/`else` statements to return the right method depending on which params I pass to the URL?
Also, I assume "String field" should be changed to `String[] field` right?

Valid requests would be:

```
/productId/freeTrial?addFields=includeDeleted,onlyActive
/productId/freeTrial?addFields=includeDeleted
/productId/freeTrial?addFields=onlyActive
/productId/freeTrial
```

Comment: would you be passing the value of `onlyActive`  as a boolean to the `retrieveFreeTrialsByProductId` method too?

Comment: so you can have now both `onlyActive` and `includeDeleted` at the same time right? or its just only one of them always?

Comment: @Ruslan Akhundov So I can have both of them(or more if ever I add more fields) at the same time. The boolean is just passed to know which part of the if/else statement in the `retrieveFreeTrialsByProductId` I want used ( yeah, I know that's code smell but I will work on that later) so I guess it could be a String aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I understand now, you can accept the following formats:

```
/productId/freeTrial?addFields=includeDeleted,onlyActive
/productId/freeTrial?addFields=includeDeleted
/productId/freeTrial?addFields=onlyActive
/productId/freeTrial
```

Get `addFields` as an array of String. Then calculate the value of the boolean you want to pass, and call your method with your boolean.

In the example below, I will assume that you only want to send `true` if 
`includeDeleted` is present and `onlyActive` is not. You can implement whatever algorithm you want.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{productId}/freeTrial", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String retrieveServiceFreeTrialsByProductIdWithParam(
      @PathVariable String productId,
      @RequestParam(value = "addFields", required = false) String[] addFields) {

    List<String> addFieldsList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(addFields!=null)
      addFieldsList = Arrays.asList(addFields);  

    boolean isIncludeDeleted = addFieldsList.contains("includeDeleted");
    boolean isOnlyActive = addFieldsList.contains("onlyActive");

    // here you define your algorithm
    boolean b = isIncludeDeleted && isOnlyActive;

    return retrieveFreeTrialsActivity().retrieveFreeTrialsByProductId(productId, b);
  }
```

Comment: How would the logic inside `retrieveFreeTrialsByProductId` look like with the 2 booleans? Would it be a switch with the 4 possible cases involving the booleans?

Comment: Well that is you to decide, I do not know what the method does. You already pass a boolean depending on the value of the first field. What do you want to do with the `isOnlyActive` parameter. ?

Comment: Ho wait I miss read the post. You want to accept a new value for your field, not a new field, is that correct? Can you add to your post what would be the 4 if/else statements you are talking about?>

Comment: That is absolutely correct. With the switch logic I meant like: if there is no addFields and no onlyActive then x; if there is an addFields and no onlyActive then y; and so on...

Comment: What is not clear is if `onlyActive` is a new param or if it is an other value for the `addFields` param. Which one is the correct format ? 
`/productId/freeTrial?addFields=includeDeleted&onlyActive=yes` or
`/productId/freeTrial?addFields=includeDeleted,onlyActive`

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at explaining myself.`/productId/freeTrial?addFields=includeDeleted,onlyActive` this one would be the correct one

Comment: No worries, I think it is clear now. I edited my answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: I would upvote you so hard if I had the reputation. Thank you very much for that, it worked perfectly

Comment: That's ok, make sure you have the latest version of my answer, I modified it a little in the past few minutes, to accept an array of Strings and to check for null.